# UWP Fullscreen BladeView Current BladeItem

Tags: c#, uwp

How do I know which `BladeItem` is being displayed when the `BladeMode` of `BladeView` is `FullScreen`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first get the inline ScrollViewer in the BladeView and then get the index of current BladeViewItem by the HorizontalOffset of ScrollViewer.

```
MyBladeView.BladeMode = Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.BladeMode.Fullscreen;
double offsetX = scrollViewer1.HorizontalOffset;​
int index = (int)(MyBladeView.ActualWidth/offsetX);
```